# Broadcast a message to all available machines on WiFi

Tags: java, android, python

my apologies if this is a trivial question.

I've recently begun doing some android programming and I'm writing a simple app that allows you to use your android device as a controller for your windows PC. Specifically it allows the user to do things like turn off the machine, make it sleep, reboot it etc etc. I'm currently using a python library called CherryPy as a server on the windows machine to execute the actual win32api calls to perform the desired function. What i'm not sure about is how to discover (dynamically) which machine on the network is actually hosting the server. Everything is working fine if I hardcode my machines public IP into the android app, but obviously that is far less than ideal. I've considered having the user manually enter their machines public IP in the app, but if there's a way to, say, broadcast a quick message to all machines on the WiFi and check for a pre-canned response that my Python server would send out, that'd be wonderful. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your app using the [alljoyn](/questions/tagged/alljoyn) framework.  [AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org) will handle these details for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending a UDP packet to the special *broadcast address* 255.255.255.255. Every device in the network should receive a copy of that packet (barring firewalls), and you can arrange to have the server reply to the packet with its identity.

Comment: So Ideally I'd be doing this at a higher level - I've been using HTTP methods rather than packet level stuff. Would this be possible at that higher abstraction?